# Need Calendar App Suggestions for Android

Tags: android, android-calendar

I've been tasked to implement an appointments app. The main screen is to display the days of the current month and which year it is and the user can perform various tasks by selecting a day and pressing one of 6 buttons.

I'm a little lost as for where to start on this. Should I create a view in XML or would it be better to do it in the code? I've read up on the calendar class but have had no luck actually getting an example working.

Any suggestions/examples on how to get started on this would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll write code to work with the layouts you create in XML

Comment: I understand that, but i know i can either do it in xml or in code. Im asking if anyone can suggest at what would be more suited to the task.

Comment: Do it in XML; it's easier to create complex layouts.

Comment: I always find that the more work I do to sketch out the layout in XML, the better I understand how the code needs to work when I get around to that

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll get to work on an xml layout and see where i get from there.

Answer (score 2):

I know there is already an accepted answer, but this might be helpful.

Creating your views in xml also helps you seperate your functionality from your ui. Similar to the [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) concept. This is considered good practice.